# Why are Relative Date filters missing on install?

Tags: dates, install

I did a fresh installation of Civi 4.7.14 with Drupal 7, and have realised that for some reason all the relative date filters are missing. I've been able to add the one I need manually at civicrm/admin/options which is good, but it would be very time consuming to do this for all of them. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Edit:
Here is a screenshot when creating a custom report. In the Activity Date drop down their should be a whole load of preset relative date filters, but you will see there is only the one: 'Last 12 months including today', which is the one that I added manually at civicrm/admin/options.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a bit more details and/or a screenshot?  I'm not clear what you are referring to.

Comment: Blinking heck if it isn't permaculture @WilliamMortada from Newcastle! Hi Will I have added a screen shot, and a bit more explaination above, so you can see better what I mean.

Comment: Hi Rob, good to get back in touch! Thanks for adding the screen shot that makes it much clearer. I haven't encountered this myself.  Have you tried replicating this on the demo site? https://civicrm.org/demo